# Matcher for checkboxes on RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec-rails, matcher, pundit

I have a Post with checkboxes for Categories like post_categories
I was trying a matcher on RSpec like:

```
expect(page).not_to have_checkbox "Sports"
```

but this matcher not exist. I'm trying different ways. But I'm having difficult on which way is the properly.
In this case what is recommended?

on the form I create a policy for show just the properly users:

```
- if policy(post).change_category?
  = f.association :categories, label: "Select the Categories:", as: :check_boxes , collection: @categories.map{|c| [c.name, c.id]}, include_hidden: false
```

Answer (score 0):

I forget to put the click_link for edit the post.

```
click_link "Edit Post"

expect(page).not_to have_css('form div.post_categories')
```